# ConnectionError ECONNREFUSED connecting to OpenSearch on localhost from asp.net core app

Tags: asp.net-core, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have an OpenSearch domain on Amazon OpenSearch Service. I use it for my asp.net core app. I now want to start using localhost by running the default docker-compose file from the quickstart docs, instead of using the Amazon OpenSearch Service (while in development). I run the docker-compose file and it is all good. But when I run my asp.net app I start to see this come through in the docker terminal:

> "error","opensearch","data"],"pid":453,"message":"[ConnectionError]:
> connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.4:9200"

**EDIT: I also see this a lot:**

> Caused by: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS
> record

I'm pretty sure the only thing I should be changing in my asp.net app is these connection strings in appsettings.json:

```
  "elasticEndpoint": "https://search-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com",
  "elasticIndexName": "vepo",
  "elasticUsername": "xxx",
  "elasticPassword": "xxx"
```

So I changed it to:

```
  "elasticEndpoint": "http://localhost:9200",
  "elasticIndexName": "vepo",
  "elasticUsername": "admin",
  "elasticPassword": "admin"
```

As far as I know that should be all that is needed, anyone know if I'm missing something or did it wrong?

I will now dump a massive amount of info below that you probably don't need but I wrote it before I found the ECONNREFUSED error and it may be useful, who knows:

Every time I start the asp.net app it deletes the default index and recreates it, then recreates every other index and populates it from my Postgres database.

This is where i create the OpenSearch client:

```
public class SearchService : ConfigurableSearchService, ISearchService
{
    private readonly string _defaultIndex;
    private readonly bool _refreshOnUpdate;
    private OpenSearchClient _client;

    public static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> SearchIndexMappings = new Dictionary<Type, string>
    {
        {typeof(VgnItmSearchDto), "vgnitmsearchdto"},
        {typeof(VgnItmEstSearchDto), "vgnitmestsearchdto"},
    };

    public string DefaultIndex { get => _defaultIndex; }

    public SearchService(
        string uri,
        string username,
        string password,
        string defaultIndex,
        bool forceInMemory = false,
        bool refreshOnUpdate = false)
       : base(SearchService.SearchIndexMappings)
    {
        ConnectionSettings connectionSettings;
        _defaultIndex = defaultIndex;
        _refreshOnUpdate = refreshOnUpdate;

        var node = new Uri(uri);
        IConnectionPool pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(node);

        connectionSettings = forceInMemory
                           ? new ConnectionSettings(pool, new InMemoryConnection())
                           : new ConnectionSettings(pool).BasicAuthentication(username, password);

        connectionSettings = connectionSettings
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

        IConnectionSettingsValues settings = connectionSettings;

        foreach (var mapping in SearchService.SearchIndexMappings)
        {
            settings.DefaultIndices.Add(mapping.Key, mapping.Value);
        }

        #if (DEBUG)
        connectionSettings.DisableDirectStreaming();
        #endif
        _client = new OpenSearchClient(connectionSettings);
    }
```

And that is called in `Startup.cs`, `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddScoped<ISearchService, SearchService>(serviceProvider =>
{
    return new SearchService(
            Configuration["elasticEndpoint"],
            Configuration["elasticUsername"],
            Configuration["elasticPassword"],
            Configuration["elasticIndexName"]);
});
```

The Configuration is using this from appsettings.json, this was the AWS one:

```
  "elasticEndpoint": "https://search-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com",
  "elasticIndexName": "xxx",
  "elasticUsername": "xxx",
  "elasticPassword": "xxx"
```

So I changed it to:

```
  "elasticEndpoint": "http://localhost:9200",
  "elasticIndexName": "vepo",
  "elasticUsername": "admin",
  "elasticPassword": "admin"
```

At the bottom of `Configure()` I tell the searchService to reindex all:

`searchIndexService.ReIndex(context, SearchIndexes.All);`

To run OpenSearch locally, I have the default docker-compose file from the quick start docs:

```
version: '3'
services:
  opensearch-node1:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
    container_name: opensearch-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the OpenSearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-node2:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
    container_name: opensearch-node2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1:9200","https://opensearch-node2:9200"]'
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  opensearch-data2:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
```

I thought that if I run OpenSearch locally with docker-compose up, then I run my asp.net app, that it would then create my indexes in my local version of OpenSearch viewable at `http://localhost:5601/app/home#/`. But it doesn't. The Create index code all runs without any exceptions.

But my indexes do not get added there. And when I perform a search, in my asp.net app I get:

> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

And the OpenSearch docker terminal shows:

> io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException:
> io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record

What am I missing that seems to be not connecting my asp.net app to my localhost version of OpenSearch?

Comment: I think `"elasticEndpoint": "http://localhost:9200",` should be `"elasticEndpoint": "https://localhost:9200",`. When I try to access opensearch dashboard with `http://localhost:9200` I get the error in log, but `https://localhost:9200` works fine.

Comment: @RafafTahsin I think that is worse as I don't see any activity in the docker terminal when I hit the endpoint from my .net app.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins, Have you tried to perform a curl request ? What works ? `http` or `https`

Comment: @Paulo how? I really don't think it is an http/https issue as I have tried both and http gets some activity. http is also the only one that works to visit the dashboard in the browser. Also I am sure I have seen it say it is at http in docker.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Most probably you need to somehow make ASP.net app to stop verify the ssl cert, as the cert provided isn't a valid certificate. https://forum.opensearch.org/t/opensearch-dashboards-security-plugin-causes-the-dashboards-to-stop-working-econnrefused/11234/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first: *If you are running your app from a docker container not use localhost, use the local IP of the host machine.*

---

I have read about the issue and I found that opensearch uses **tls certificates** for all connections: node-node, and client-node.

https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/configuration/tls/

So you could create and install the certificates by yourself to allow your app (client) to connect to the local cluster (node). But if you think is not necessary to install these certificates in the local deployment, I suggest you avoid the SSL verification.

---

**before all**, if you have curl (bash terminal) execute this command:

```bash
   curl https://admin:admin@localhost:9200 -k
```

the **-k** asks curl not make ssl validation and admin:admin is username:password. And if the command works this solution will work for you.

### Disabling the Security plugin in Opensearch

in docker-composer.yaml add  "DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true" to the environments:

```yaml
    ...
    container_name: opensearch-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster # Name the cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1 # Name the node that will run in this container
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2 # Nodes to look for when discovering the cluster
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2 # Nodes eligible to serve as cluster manager
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # Disable JVM heap memory swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # Set min and max JVM heap sizes to at least 50% of system RAM
      - "DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true"
    ...
```

and

```yaml
    ...
    container_name: opensearch-node2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true"
    ...
```

now you can use **http** instead https:

```bash
curl http://admin:admin@localhost:9200
```

### Disabling SSL on your app

I'm not good at asp net core but I made a test **disabling SSL** validation and it worked(using HttpClient and your composer.yaml file).

```cs
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
        (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
    {
        return true;
    };
    string url = "https://localhost:9200";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"{jsonResponse}\n");
```

**YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=** is a base64 string encode from "user:password" ("admin:admin")

**the output:**

```json
{
  "name" : "opensearch-node1",
  "cluster_name" : "opensearch-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "mHWmnO2ORguqfe4F-0nJrQ",
  "version" : {
    "distribution" : "opensearch",
    "number" : "2.8.0",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "db90a415ff2fd428b4f7b3f800a51dc229287cb4",
    "build_date" : "2023-06-03T06:24:25.112415503Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.10.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}
```

As you can see it works, so I think you should look into OpenSearch.Client package to know how to disable SSL and if it is possible, you have a solution.

### Nginx solution

Also, you can see the issue from outside of your application: your app needs an endpoint and doesn't need to concern about certificates. So we can provide an endpoint ready to consume without SSL certificates.

**How ?**
Using an Nginx container as a reverse proxy for "https://opensearch-node1:9200". Nginx proxy by default does not validate SSL certificates, then you could make a request to http://nginx-service:80 and it will work.

steps:

1. create a **nginx.conf** file in the same folder of docker-compose.yaml and paste it into it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

        
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://opensearch-node1:9200;
    }
}
```

2. add this service to your **docker-composer.yaml**

```yaml
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
```

3. start your containers:

```bash
docker-compose up
```

4. test if the nginx works with curl (of another tool like Postman):

```bash
curl http://admin:admin@localhost
```

5. change the endpoint in your asp net core app, for example:

```cs
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; init; }
        public string FirstName { get; init; }
        public string LastName { get; init; }
        public int GradYear { get; init; }
        public double Gpa { get; init; }
    }

    string url = "http://localhost";
    Console.WriteLine(url);
    var node = new Uri(url);
    var config = new ConnectionSettings(node).BasicAuthentication("admin", "admin").DefaultIndex("students");
    var client = new OpenSearchClient(config);
    Console.WriteLine($"{config}\n");
    var student = new Student { Id = 100, FirstName = "Paulo", LastName = "Santos", Gpa = 3.93, GradYear = 2021 };
    var response = client.Index(student, i => i.Index("students")); 
    Console.WriteLine($"{response}\n");
```

```bash
Valid OpenSearch.Client response built from a successful (201) low level call on PUT: /students/_doc/100
```

6. read indexes:

```bash
curl http://admin:admin@localhost/students/_doc/100
```

```json
{"_index":"students","_id":"100","_version":2,"_seq_no":1,"_primary_term":2,"found":true,"_source":{"id":100,"firstName":"Paulo","lastName":"Santos","gradYear":2021,"gpa":3.93}}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I only did docker-composer.yaml add "DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true". The rest either didn't work (the first step couldn't connect) or seemed like it would have undesirable consequences, when I only wanted to get local openSearch working, while AWS hosted openSearch is working with https. I did also change to use my ip address in "elasticEndpoint": "http://192.168.1.21:9200" though.

Comment: what is the output of the "curl http://192.168.1.21:9200 " with DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true ?

Comment: Failed to connect to 192.168.1.21 port 9200 after 5 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Comment: it worked from another terminal after docker-compose up was still running. What is it really doing? Is it basically the same effect as DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true?

Comment: curl is just for testing the status of the endpoint (like Postman or a browser). I think your services spend much time to be available,  it is for that reason that the curl command first failed with a timeout, and after it worked ...